# What does the Thai Fighter pilot say in Family Guy: Blue Harvest?

Tags: star-wars, family-guy

In the Star Wars parody Family Guy: Blue Harvest, what does the Thai Fighter pilot say?

Here's the clip.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Thai Fighter yelled in his battle cry:

> "Die, all of you! I'll kill your father with my laser gun!"

Source: http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Blue_Harvest/Notes/Trivia